# Facebook authentication Issue in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created one new user in facebook but I am unable to login. And 
  when I am using the old facebook account then its working fine.

I am using omniauth-facebook gem for Facebook authentication. So, for 
  that I am using version

```
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 4.0.0'.
```

Now graph api version has updated.So, I have added graph api version like this.

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0"
```

But still I am not able to figure out what is the issue. 
Can anyone please help me? Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question with logs from your server ? What error message the request/the gem is returning ?

Comment: I am not getting any error message.

Comment: At least your app logs.